# How do I speed up this double loop by vectorization in R?

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have two datatables. One with information about houses, including two columns with coordinates (one for East and one for Nord). And one with information about stations including two columns with coordinates. The coordinates are in Swiss LV95 format.

```
    > head(d.small)
         id   GKODE   GKODN
1:      100 2608850 1262583
2: 10000012 2612952 1267232
3: 11776807 2612952 1267232
4: 10000061 2623360 1247413
5: 10000223 2622938 1259411
6:  9997602 2609194 1262383

> head(haltestelle.small)
   y_Koord_Ost x_Koord_Nord
1:     2633061      1257737
2:     2630544      1252831
3:     2628497      1256841
4:     2629649      1255767
5:     2619156      1264531
6:     2619741      1247012
```

Now I need the distance to the closest station.

My code below calculates the distance between one house and all the stations, takes the minimum distance and adds the according index.

Unfortunately, my code is far too slow. How do I vectorize my loop?

```
dist.oev <- data.table(dist.oev=rep(1, nrow(d.small)), dist.oev.index=rep(1, nrow(d.small)))

for (i in 1:nrow(d.small)) {
  cat(i, " ")
  for ( j in 1:nrow(haltestelle.small)) {
    diff.ost <- d.small[i, .(GKODE)] - haltestelle.small[j, .(y_Koord_Ost)]
    diff.nord <- d.small[i, .(GKODN)] - haltestelle.small[j, .(x_Koord_Nord)]
    dist.oev[i,1] <- min(sqrt(diff.ost^2 + diff.nord^2))
    dist.oev[i,2] <- which.min(sqrt(diff.ost^2 + diff.nord^2))
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add sample data and exactly what the loop does to get alternative answers. Loops have in most cases already been implemented in R functions negating the need to rewrite loops.

Comment: e.g. try `dput(d.small)`

Comment: It looks like the distance formula you are using is the standard distance formula. What make your coordinate system special?

Comment: Example still not reproducible: `Error: object 'dist.oev' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
d.small[,
        mindist := sqrt(min((GKODE - haltestelle.small[["y_Koord_Ost"]])^2 +
                            (GKODN - haltestelle.small[["x_Koord_Nord"]])^2)),
        by = id]

#          id   GKODE   GKODN   mindist
# 1:      100 2608850 1262583 10488.486
# 2: 10000012 2612952 1267232  6766.463
# 3: 11776807 2612952 1267232  6766.463
# 4: 10000061 2623360 1247413  3641.148
# 5: 10000223 2622938 1259411  6124.327
# 6:  9997602 2609194 1262383 10190.944
```

Data (in a reproducible format):

```
d.small <- fread("id   GKODE   GKODN
     100 2608850 1262583
10000012 2612952 1267232
11776807 2612952 1267232
10000061 2623360 1247413
10000223 2622938 1259411
 9997602 2609194 1262383")

haltestelle.small <- fread("y_Koord_Ost x_Koord_Nord
2633061      1257737
2630544      1252831
2628497      1256841
2629649      1255767
2619156      1264531
2619741      1247012")
```

With just minor edits your code is bug free:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(d.small)) {
  diff.ost  <- d.small[i, GKODE] - haltestelle.small[, y_Koord_Ost]
  diff.nord <- d.small[i, GKODN] - haltestelle.small[, x_Koord_Nord]
  dist.oev[i,1] <- sqrt(min(diff.ost^2 + diff.nord^2)) # take sqrt outside min for efficiency
  dist.oev[i,2] <- which.min(diff.ost^2 + diff.nord^2) # sqrt unnecessary (monotonic transformation)
}
```

Get the indices also with something like this:

```
d.small[,
        c("mindist", "mindist_index") := {
          dist = (GKODE - haltestelle.small[["y_Koord_Ost"]])^2 + (GKODN - haltestelle.small[["x_Koord_Nord"]])^2
          .(sqrt(min(dist)), which.min(dist))
        },
        by = id]
```

Comment: sindri_baldur thank you very much for your fast response! adapting your code to my data it results the same numbers as the code from @citronrose. but the results from my loop differ. I can't see why

Comment: @AdrianWüest there is a bug in your loop, you are always comparing to the last row of `haltestelle.small` and not selecting the minimum.

Comment: oh dear, thanks a lot @sindri_baldur! that solved my problem perfectly!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should be relatively fast as long as it fits into your RAM. I include a reproducible example, even though it's not your exact data. `h` contains your station coordinates and `d` contains your house coordinates:

```
h <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(500),y=rnorm(500))
xdiff <- sapply(h$x,function(x1)sapply(d$x,function(x2)(x1-x2)^2))
ydiff <- sapply(h$y,function(y1)sapply(d$y,function(y2)(y1-y2)^2))
dist2 <-  xdiff+ydiff
closest <- apply(dist2,1,which.min)
min.dist <- sqrt(dist2[cbind(seq(500),closest)])
```

The code first computes all squared differences in x and then all the squared differences in y and adds them to get the squared euclidean distance in a matrix.

Comment: thank you very much for the fast response! if adapt your code to my data it gives a different results! I can't see why!

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the `sf`-package:

(I am not sure if I've got latitude and longitude right, since I'm not familiar with 
LV95-formatting.)

#### Sample data

```
# Sample data
library(data.table)
d.small <- fread("id   GKODE   GKODN
100 2608850 1262583
10000012 2612952 1267232
11776807 2612952 1267232
10000061 2623360 1247413
10000223 2622938 1259411
9997602 2609194 1262383")

haltestelle.small <- fread("y_Koord_Ost x_Koord_Nord
2633061      1257737
2630544      1252831
2628497      1256841
2629649      1255767
2619156      1264531
2619741      1247012")
```

#### Code

```
# Create spatial objects
library(sf)
d.sf <- d.small %>% sf::st_as_sf( coords = c("GKODE", "GKODN"), crs = 2056)     
haltestelle.sf <- haltestelle.small %>% sf::st_as_sf( coords = c("y_Koord_Ost", "x_Koord_Nord"), crs = 2056) 

# Calculate nearest haltestelle for each d.small
d.sf %>% 
  dplyr::group_by( id ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( np = sf::st_nearest_feature( geometry, haltestelle.sf ),
                 dist_np = as.numeric( sf::st_distance( geometry, d.sf[np,] ) ) )
```

#### Output

```
        id    np dist_np          geometry
     <int> <int>   <dbl>       <POINT [m]>
1      100     5  14441. (2608850 1262583)
2 10000012     5  12684. (2612952 1267232)
3 11776807     5  12684. (2612952 1267232)
4 10000061     6  20610. (2623360 1247413)
5 10000223     3  12684. (2622938 1259411)
6  9997602     5  14062. (2609194 1262383)
```